# Observable of Observable collection in template

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-template

Since the title definitely doesn't further my intent, here's what I'm trying to do.

I want to display a list of items in the view, which I get asynchronously from the backend (I have a service with a method called `fetchItems()` to fetch them that has an `Observable<Item[]>` return type).
I initialize this list in the component constructor by setting `this.items = this.itemService.fetchItems();`.
I display this list of items in the view by doing `*ngFor="let item of items | async"`.

So far, so good, everything works as expected.

Each item has a field `subItemId`. I want to use this key to display, in the aforementioned list, the actual sub item object of type `SubItem`. I can get this item through `this.subItemService.findById(subItemId)`, which returns `Observable<SubItem>`.

How do I go about doing this?

I obviously can't have a component method like `getSubItem(item: Item): SubItem` that I call from the template, since it will get called over and over.
I don't want to modify the `itemService.fetchItem()` method to eagerly load the sub items since they might not be needed everywhere it is used.

The answer might be obvious, but I've only been working with Angular (6) for a couple of days.

Comment: You don't want to eagerly load subItems, but what is the condition when you have to load a subitem? Is it a user event?

Comment: In the current component the they are always required, but the service for fetching the main items is used elsewhere as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reconstruct parent child relations of item > subitem using rxjs operators. Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsxkse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts):

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  itemsWithSubItems: Observable<any>;
  subItems: Observable<any[]>;
  getItems(): Observable<{ subItemId: number, itemName: string, subItem?: any }[]> {
    return of([{ subItemId: 1, itemName: 'One'}, { subItemId: 2, itemName: 'Two' }, { subItemId: 3, itemName: 'Three' }, { subItemId: 4, itemName: 'Four' }])
      .pipe(shareReplay());
  }

  constructor() {
    this.itemsWithSubItems = this.getItems().pipe(
        flatMap(items => from(items)),
        switchMap(item => this.getSubItemById(item.subItemId), 
          (outerValue, innerValue, outerIndex, innerIndex) => {
            outerValue.subItem = innerValue;
            return outerValue
          }),
        toArray());
    this.itemsWithSubItems.subscribe(x => console.log('x', x))
  }

  getSubItemById(subItemId: number): Observable<{name: string}> {
    return of({ name: `${subItemId}-SubItem` });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've used `async` in the template which means that the data binding for the template is lazy loaded. So there is nothing you can really do but use `async` again for child item.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    <span>{{(getSubItem(item: Item) | async)?.title}}</span>
</div>
```

The above would call a function which returns an observable, and the `?` means that the result is optional before the `title` property is read.

You can see what the limitation here is. If you need more than a single property you have to perform another `async` operation. It's just not practical.

You need to either load all the data for the template or change your API back-end to fetch all data in a single API call.

You'll end up needing something like this.

```
 this.itemService.fetchItems().first().subscribe((items)=>{ 
       this.items = items;
       this.items.forEach((item)=>{ 
            this.getSubItem(item).first().subscribe((sub)=> {
                 // attach the child to the parent item
                 item.child = sub;
            });
       });
 });
```

You can then iterate over `items` in the template, and use `item.child` for the sub-item of that parent. You'll need to use the `?` operator since the data is lazy loaded and won't exist the first time the items are rendered.

Comment: The first option isn't really viable since it keeps making that request (for the sub item) to the server due to what I assume is the mechanism by which Angular does the binding (by repeatedly evaluating the value).

Comment: When you return an object as the value the expression is seen as changing if each call creates a new object. The trick is to return the same object for the same inputs each time.